# Play list of songs in dancer.js

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I want to play a list of songs using [dancer.js](https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js/). The examples they have given in the `Examples` folder is playing only ONE song after I click play in the browser. I have a list of songs in my `songs` folder and want to be able to play these one after another or randomly.  I am new at JavaScript.

How can I do this?